# Xcode 8 Beta 6 Swift 3 Argument List Error

Tags: swift3, xcode8-beta6

I am using CloudKit and have a `Model` class with a method which saves user preferences to the cloud database. I have successfully updated my Swift 3 syntax to account for the latest proposals released with Xcode 8 beta 6. However, I have one last error left which I can't seem to resolve. The code for my function is:

```
func savePreferences(preferences: UserPreferences, completion:
       @escaping (CKRecord?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    privateDatabase.save(preferences.record) {
        record, error in
        completion(record, error)
    }
}
```

The signature for the `record` property of the `UserPreferences`instance used here is:

```
var record : CKRecord
```

`privateDatabase` is a `CKDatabase`.

The error I receive is:

`Cannot invoke 'save' with an argument list of type (CKRecord, (CKRecord?, Error?) -> Void)`

I have found that removing the call to `completion` causes the error to disappear and allows a successful build.

I'm hoping someone can tell me where I am going wrong or if this is a bug with Xcode 8 beta 6.

Comment: You probably need to use `Error` instead of `NSError` in your `completion` closure.

Comment: Yep, embarrassing I didn't spot that! Thanks man, you should make that an answer to this question.